# What JavaScript libraries have the following controls

Tags: javascript, web-controls

We're porting a WinForms app (making massive use of a lot of the DevExpress controls) to HTML5/JavaScript (with a backing REST/JSON web service).

What quality JavaScript control libraries out there have the following:

1. TreeView. Where each node can have multiple distinct links (that call a function) and a bitmap at the end.
2. Grid (can be simple read/only).
3. [PropertyGrid (view/edit all properties in an object)](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/ctodx/PropertyGrid.png), with customized handling for numbers, enumerated lists, etc.
4. [Accordion](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theprogressbar/Silverlight_Navigation_Bar_View_Scroll_Bar_0D530B88.png).
5. Tab group control.
6. Wizard control.
7. Pop-up menu on click.
8. Menu bar (doesn't need to be ribbon, but does need to support bitmaps).

note: I am **not** asking which is best (disallowed here). I am asking what control sets have this functionality.

Comment: I don't think asking for a list of all such libraries is any better than asking for which is "best." It's still a shopping question.

Comment: I view it as a resource question. What ones out there have it. By leaving aside which is best (changes rapidly over time) it leaves a listing of products to start with. And that answer will remain correct 5 years from now.

Comment: Lists of things just don't belong here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124450/133242 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180335/133242

Comment: You probably will find these features in most popular libraries (native or as a plugin)

Comment: @MattBall - I'm missing something here because the second link you provided said "But could a "list" question be acceptable if it is a factual, "short-list question" - and this is definitely a factual (very clear criteria) short list (looks like only 3 libraries) question. So why is it closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ext JS has this functionality: http://sencha.com/products/extjs

Comment: Thank you - this looks like it has everything.

Answer (score 2):

The dijit namespace of the dojo toolkit has most, if not all, of these widgets.

The dojox namespace which is to dojo as javax is to java also has some pretty nifty widgets if the dijit ones don't quite fit your needs.

The dgrid project which comes from the same house as dojo and is built off dojo will help with your grid needs (and, potentially, your tree needs)

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at Ext JS first as I prefer a commercial product (easier to get support). But this will be my backup.

Answer (score 1):

YUI(Yahoo User Interface), you can refer to  http://yuilibrary.com/